# Replace duplicates of block size less than Threshold - Python

Tags: python

How do I remove consecutive duplicates of block size less than some threshold (say 4 here) from a list like this in python?

> L = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]

I want the result to be like this:

> O = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

The new list should also replace the consecutive duplicates of block size less than threshold (here 4) with neighbor values (like filling with neighbors).

I was thinking of some king of smoothing filter but couldn't find. Also, i was thinking of writing raw code for this but not able to think of logic.

Assume that it is binary list.

Comment: Hint: `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: What would be the output for [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0] with threshold 4?

Comment: @Piinthesky i figured it is little complex if the initial block size itself is not of size threshold. I solved my problem with itertools.groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ has stated, you can use `itertools.groupby` to achieve what you want.

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]
ans = []

for (i,j) in groupby(L):
    a = list(j)
    if len(a)<4: # replace with threshold
        ans = ans + [1-i]*len(a) # not of a binary value i = 1-i
    else:
        ans = ans + a
print(ans)
```

Output :

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I would appreciate comments to make the code better, if possible.

Comment: Yeah.. i had solved the problem with itertools.groupby suggested by COLDSPEED.

Comment: Thank you Miraj50 for your answer.